# ParametricPlot Evaluate a fuction with two parameters

Tags: plotting

I am trying to evaluate and plot a parametric function by altering the initial conditions with two parameters. The evaluation parts works ok but i am having problem plotting it. I tried to use Flatten but i do something wrong. It works ok with just one parameter instead of two and without flatten
Here is my code and thank you in advance

```
q0 = 5.3;
ε0 = 2.2;
Γ = 5/3;
μ = 0.001;
ψ0 = 40;
l = μ/2;
Ω0 = 10.112;

ω0[s_] := (l R[s] μ)/((l^2 + R[s]^2)^2)
h0[s_] := Sqrt[1 - (R[s]*μ)/(l^2 + R[s]^2)] 
U0[s_] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2)


sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)
sG[s_] := sM0[s]/U0[s]
Dsonic[s_] := (-(-1 + Γ) ε0^2 + (-2 + Γ) ε0^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1) +
h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3)
dΔ0[s_] := (q0 Δ0[s] + 
Δ0[s]^Γ) ε0^2 (-2 R[s]^2 + (l^2 + R[s]^2) F[s]) Δ0[s]^(2 Γ)


dF[s_] := 
F[s]*Dsonic[s] + (F[s]^2 (h0[s]^2 - sM0[s]))/(4 π R[s]^2 sG[s]^2)*
Dsonic[s]


δc = 10^-4;
R0 = 0.10465641807783241`;
F0 = 1.9881644662604596`;
Δ00 = 16.5;
Rinit = R0 + δc*m1;
Δinit = Δ00 + δc*Sqrt[1 - m1^2]*Cos[\[Phi]] ;
Finit = F0 + δc*Sqrt[1 - m1^2]*Sin[\[Phi]] ;
m1min = -1;
m1max = 1;
mstep = 0.5;
\[Phi]min = 0;
\[Phi]max = 2 π;
\[Phi]step = π/3;
 smax = 0.1;

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{F'[s] == dF[s], Δ0'[s] == dΔ0[s]*Dsonic[s], 
R'[s] == Dsonic[s], F[0] == Finit, Δ0[0] == Δinit, 
R[0] == Rinit}, {F, Δ0, R}, {s, 0, smax}, {m1, \[Phi]}]


ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[Flatten[
Table[{R[m1, \[Phi]][s], 
  F[s] /. {R[s] :> R[m1, \[Phi]][s], Δ0[s] :> Δ0[m1, \[Phi]][s], 
    F[s] :> F[m1, \[Phi]][s]}} /. sol, {m1, m1min, m1max, 
 mstep}, {\[Phi], \[Phi]min, \[Phi]max, \[Phi]step}], {s, 0, 
 smax}, AspectRatio -> 1]]]
```

Comment: `ParametricPlot[
 Flatten[Table[{R[m1, ϕ][s], 
     F[s] /. {R[s] :> 
        R[m1, ϕ][s], Δ0[
         s] :> Δ0[m1, ϕ][s], 
       F[s] :> F[m1, ϕ][s]}} /. sol, {m1, m1min, m1max, 
    mstep}, {ϕ, ϕmin, ϕmax, ϕstep}]], {s, 0, 
  smax}, AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: You don't need to use **Evaluate**; 

`ParametricPlot[
 Flatten[Table[{R[m1, \[Phi]][s], 
     F[s] /. {R[s] :> 
        R[m1, \[Phi]][s], \[CapitalDelta]0[
         s] :> \[CapitalDelta]0[m1, \[Phi]][s], 
       F[s] :> F[m1, \[Phi]][s]}} /. sol, {m1, m1min, m1max, 
    mstep}, {\[Phi], \[Phi]min, \[Phi]max, \[Phi]step}]], {s, 0, 
  smax}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Thank you both. It works just as you suggested